# How to convert DATETIME in specific format to DATE in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I apologize for asking a simple question, but I could not find the answer on the forum.
I need to convert from this datetime '2009-06-18T00:00:00+06:00' to format 'YYYY-MM-DD' in PL/SQL.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with PL/SQL? You have it in the title, in the question, and the tags - but I see no need for it. I hope you don't think PL/SQL is a name for Oracle SQL? It isn't.

Comment: Then: Is the input a string? Or is it in fact in the DATE data type? (Unlikely - they aren't shown with a T in Oracle). And the resulting time - should that be midnight, or do you need to convert for time zone? The input shows a time zone of UTC + 6 hours, does that matter? Or do you just need the date (YYYY-MM-DD) and disregard any time zone adjustment?

Comment: The input is string. Value comes from webservice. I need only date (YYYY-MM-DD) and disregard any time zone adjustment.

Comment: And what do you need as output, a date (in the Oracle DATE data type), or a string again?

Answer (score 4):

If this "datetime" is really a timestamp (as it looks like), not a string, then you can choose how to display it (using TO_CHAR) or convert to DATE (using TO_DATE), or simply TRUNCATE it. Note that the last two *results* (i.e. the way they are displayed) depend on current NLS settings (set by my ALTER SESSION).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test
  2       as (select to_timestamp_tz ('2009-06-18T00:00:00+06:00',
  3                                   'yyyy-mm-dd"t"hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzm')
  4                     col
  5             from dual)
  6  select to_char (col, 'yyyy-mm-dd') res1,
  7         to_date (to_char (col, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') res2,
  8         trunc (col) res3
  9    from test;

RES1       RES2       RES3
---------- ---------- ----------
2009-06-18 18.06.2009 18.06.2009

SQL>
```

Comment: I think for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you should better run `alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'dd.mm.yyyy';` `nls_date_format` applies only for `DATE` values, i.e. `RES2` and `RES3`

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_DATE` on the first 10 characters in your timestamp string:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2009-06-18T00:00:00+06:00', 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is the best part.

http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date

you can use the `TO_DATE(string, format)` function for that so it will be like

`SELECT TO_DATE('2012-06-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM xyz;`

Comment: I would not consider this link as "documentation"

Answer (score 0):

DEPENDS on the data type.

If the column is DATE data type, then, as suggested already, TRUNC would do the job to display. But, if your locale-specific NLS date settings are different, then you will still see the time portion as midnight.

Else, you need to use TO_DATE with proper FORMAT and apply TRUNC to it.

update

If you only want to display, use TO_CHAR, else, if you have a filter in your WHERE clause, then remember TO_CHAR doesn't return DATE, it converts it into literal.